# Validate Create Account request

Tags: php, sql

I'm making an app that uses tokens to validate a user. Once the user is logged in they receive a token and to do anything that involves inserting data into my database the token must be validated.

However, this has lead to a problem. Creating an account involves inserting data into my database but I can't use the token authentication system since they don't have a token as a result of them not being logged in.

Below is an example of how the authentication works with a token

```
<?php
    if(authenticationIsValid($token)){
        doSomething()
    }else{
        exit(0)
    }
?>
```

My problem is right now my create account script looks like below

```
<?php
    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    createAccount($username,$password);
?>
```

and if the url were lets say `www.domain.com/createaccount.php` and someone found out. They could easily insert 1000's of accounts into my database.

Any recommendations?

EDIT:

Is the only solution sending the user an email confirmation?

Comment: What criteria should be met to allow someone to make an account? Why not require an existing administrative user to create or approve accounts.

Comment: This is for an app where anyone can make an account. An approval process wouldn't work. I need to know how like Google for example lets users create accounts without their database becoming vulnerable.

Comment: Seeing the added comment ^ - the question is now too broad. What you need to take into consideration are prepared statements and a safe password storage method like `password_hash()`.

Comment: If it's a public app, I guess I fail to see why someone making thousands of accounts is a problem. Maybe look into a captcha if you want to protect it from automated usage. Otherwise I agree with Fred.

Comment: *"EDIT: Is the only solution sending the user an email confirmation?"* - Yes, a unique token that can only be used once and a time restraint.

Comment: Google(Gmail) also uses/offers a 2-step verification system which would go beyond the scope of the question. It's doable but will require more than comments as there are quite a few things involved with this. What you need to do once they create their account is for them to be verified first. You can't place the wagon before the horse, *as it were.* Once verified, you can `UPDATE` the database with a boolean flag. If I didn't "answer" the question, then wait for someone else to visit the question; good luck. IMHO, I feel I have.

Comment: *"and if the url were lets say www.domain.com/createaccount.php and someone found out. They could easily insert 1000's of accounts into my database."* - Well, that's only if that file doesn't use additional parameters like `createaccount.php?email=encoded_email&token=xxx` type of thing. Plus, use a UNIQUE constraint for email/user id's in db, and check if any exist beforehand. If so, kick 'em out.

Comment: I stayed here long enough. You can ping me if you want; I left the question.

Comment: Can create another token system for the createaccount page.

Comment: Add a captcha script to create the accoAdd.